# How to debug python scripts that fork

Tags: python, debugging, fork

In perl debugger I can use DB::get_fork_TTY() to debug both parent and child process in different terminals.  Is there anything similar in python debugger?
Or, is there any good way to debug fork in python?

Comment: There's no earthly reason to do a fork in Python in the first place.  You have much, much better ways to implement multi-processing.  Why are you trying to fork?  Please provide some details.

Comment: @S.Lott  I'm trying to rewrite some old script from perl to python.  The old perl script using fork. The child process do the necessary job.  The parent process is waiting.  If timeout (e.g. running longer than 30 minutes), it kill the child.

Comment: Take a look at the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module or the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module.

Comment: For similar scenario's I've used pyDBGP.  Not perfect but you can do pydbgp.brk(host="devWorkstation.tld") and it will connect the running process to Komodo IDE.  Unfortunately it requires Komodo IDE as that's the only IDE I know that supports pyDBGP

Comment: @vicshen: Please **update** your question so that the question contains all the facts.  Code samples help.

Comment: After some more investigation, I agree it's not necessary to use fork() in my job.  Thanks for S.Lott and agf.
But I'm still curious if there's any similar feature in python debugger.  I happen to find this feature in perldb and I find it's very handy.  After the fork() statement, it will pop up another terminal so you can debug parent process in one terminal and debug child process in another terminal.  Both process are in the control.  It also improves my understanding on the old perl script which uses fork because I can clearly see how these 2 processes interact in the debugger.

Comment: @David  Thanks. But for now, I have no plan to try Komodo IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can emulate forked process if you will set instead of fork and its condition (pid == 0) always True. For debugging main process debugger will work.

For debugging multi-processing interaction better to use detailed logs as for me

Comment: This is the only useful answer here. If you get handed a daemon someone else wrote and they've used fork, are you going to rewrite the whole damn thing?

Comment: I don't know any remote debugger for python. Daemons are forked to get rid of any parent process files descriptors, including stdin, stderr and stdout, the only way to trace them -- use loggers, usual log or syslog.

Comment: In my case I was just able to add a debug option to the daemon, which just skips around the fork and so runs the main part blocking, in a well-written daemon it shouldnt make much difference.

Comment: Unfortunately, it might not work if there's some IPC going on between the two processes :(

Answer (score 1):

The debugger in pyCharm does this nicely. It seems to use gdb with python support to accomplish that, however all the tutorials on how to do this with gdb by Hand which I've found so far didn't work for me. In pyCharm it just works.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to debug a fork is to use pdb on the main process and winpdb on the fork. You put a software break early in the fork process and attach the winpdb app once the break has been hit.

It might be possible to run the program under winpdb and attach another instance after the fork - I haven't tried this. You certainly can't attach two winpdb instances at the same time, I've tried and it fails. If it works, this would be preferable - pdb *really* sucks.

Answer (score 0):

Provided Python has not been stripped of its debugging symbols and gdb (version above 7.0) is available, you can attach to the child and use pdb commands to debug it with:

```
pdb-clone --pid CHILD_PID
```

pdb-clone is at Pypi: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdb-clone/

Answer (score -17):

> But I'm still curious if there's any similar feature in python debugger. I happen to find this feature in perldb and I find it's very handy

No.

You don't need it.

No matter how handy it may appear in other environments, you just don't need it.

You don't need `fork()` in Python; therefore you don't need fancy debugging to work with `fork()`.

If you think you need `fork()` you should either use `subprocess`, `multiprocessing` or C.

Comment: Typical stackoverflow non-answer.

Comment: I note that subprocess is implemented with fork() under unix. In fact, that's exactly what I'm currently trying to debug.